# Pusher : No callbacks on test for pusher for my event

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I am trying to get this test where I get each object I create, broadcasted without refreshing the page.
Here is the js where we instantiate pusher and bind the event for UserHasRegistered:

```
<script src="https://js.pusher.com/4.1/pusher.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            // Enable pusher logging - don't include this in production
            Pusher.logToConsole = true;
            (function() {
                var pusher = new Pusher('3c50750503376de6d201', {
                    cluster: 'eu',
                    encrypted: true
                });
                var channel = pusher.subscribe('test');
                channel.bind('App\\Events\\UserHasRegistered', function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                });
            })();
            </script>
```

This is the route where I broadcast a registered user name, which I also mention in the binding to pusher.

```
         Route::get('broadcast', function(){
              $name = Request::input('name');
              event(new UserHasRegistered($name));
              return 'Done';
              });
```

The event Listener is working, I got the env setup as well as the broadcast.php, but this is what I get:

```
  Pusher : State changed : initialized -> connecting  pusher.min.js:8:2561
Pusher : Connecting : {"transport":"ws","url":"wss://ws-eu.pusher.com:443             /app/3c50750503376de6d201?protocol=7&client=js&version=4.1.0&flash=false"}       pusher.min.js:8:2561
Pusher : State changed : connecting -> connected with new socket ID 123754.768449  pusher.min.js:8:2561
Pusher : Event sent : {"event":"pusher:subscribe","data":{"channel":"test"}}  pusher.min.js:8:2561
Pusher : Event recd : {"event":"pusher_internal:subscription_succeeded","data":{},"channel":"test"}        pusher.min.js:8:2561
Pusher : No callbacks on test for pusher:subscription_succeeded     pusher.min.js:8:2561
```

Comment: Do you bind JavaScript and PHP classes?

Comment: https://laracasts.com/series/whats-new-in-laravel-5-1/episodes/12 according this this, i suppose.

Comment: At 15:13 in the video it is done with vue, he binds it with the class.

Answer (score 1):

You should use both. To catch the error and subscribe to your channel:

```
channel.bind('pusher:subscription_succeeded', function(members) {
    // alert('successfully subscribed!');
 });

 channel.bind("App\\Events\\UserHasRegistered", function(data) {
     console.log(data);
 });
```

Since you can bind to more than one event.